# Return a varchar from database using dapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I need to retrieve a single word/varchar from the database ( it can be an empty string or a null value sometimes ).
I'm using dapper and I can't retrieve anything at all. The many tutorials and questions on the Web refer only to retrieve an **Integer** value, but never a **String**.

This is what I got so far:

```
 using (var db = new FbConnection(csb.ToString()))
                {
                    await db.OpenAsync();
                    result = db.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>("SELECT NOME from NACION WHERE NOME = @nacion", new { nacion }).ToString();
                    db.Close();
                }
```

That `result` variable should be a string, like **"Word"** or an empty/null string, depending on the result of the query.

Right now, it's returning something weird like this: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task'1[System.String]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to await the task, i.e. `result = await db.Execute....`.

Comment: If something isn't a string don't just call `ToString()`. Check *why* it's not what you thought it would be. BTW you don't need to call `db.Close()` explicitly, this will happen as soon as execution leaves the `using` block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should await the call to the method `ExecuteScalarAsync`:

```
result = await db.ExecuteScalarAsync<string>(...);
```

Please note that you **should not** to call `ToString()`.

Comment: (what you said) ... **and** you should remove the unnecessary `ToString()` invokation.

Comment: I did leave it out in my example :-)

Comment: Thank you, it worked... I realise now that this was a dumb question... :/ 
Anyway, appreciated your help!